# Do we need the `setup` tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we need an actual [setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/setup) tag?  I mean, for all intents and purposes, [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation) should suffice for setup questions related to Ubuntu, no?

Answer (score 13):

We don't need these to be separate tags. [setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/setup) should be made a synonym of [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation).

[installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation) does apply to things other than Ubuntu as a whole (I can install a program, which would be within the scope of that tag ...I can install more memory in my computer, which might not be within that scope.) But so can [setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/setup). I doubt we gain anything by having these as separate tags.

As a separate point, [as Seth says](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7064/22949), [setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/setup) seems to refer to an even wider range of unrelated topics than [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation), with less clarity as to what falls in its scope. I can set up a new user account, a second monitor, document templates in LibreOffice, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think we need [setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/setup). It's too ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, setup comes after installation (installation->setup). You usually install once and able to setup configurations several times.